# Bootstrap/bind click event over ngClick

Tags: javascript, angular.js, event-handling

I am working on angularjs, and I have created some directives with bunch of HTML elements within its templates. I have assigned a controller for those directives.  Below is my code snippet:

```
directives.directive('ngLd',function()
{
    return {
        restrict : "AE",
        templateUrl:'partials/ld.html',
        scope:{},
        link : function(scope,element,attr)
        {
            var lbutton = element.find("span[class='lb-lk-comm']");
            var dlbutton = element.find("span[class='lb-dlk-comm']");
            if(lbutton && dlbutton)
            {
                lbutton.bind('click',function(event)
                {
                    scope.likeAction(lbutton.hasClass("lb-voted-comm"),dlbutton.hasClass("lb-voted-comm"));
                    scope.$apply(); 
                });
                dlbutton.bind('click',function(event)
                {
                    scope.dislikeAction(lbutton.hasClass("lb-voted-comm"),dlbutton.hasClass("lb-voted-comm"));
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        },
        controller : "MyController"
    };
});
```

In the above code, I have used a link function of bind the click event on required elements.
Another approach I could have followed to use the `ngClick` directive directly over the elements, but that is sort of exposing method to client end.

My question is, am I following a good approach by binding click event ? or should I use `ngClick` ?

I am using `angular.bootstrap(document,"myApp");` to bootstrap the angular module to document, so I was wondering if I could have similar thing to dynamically bind those events (click, hover, change etc) to my HTML elements, without exposing them to HTML pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did the right thing, if you used `ngClick` you would loose tooling: syntax highlighting, debugging, linting.

Other than that your code looks good, some minor nitpickings:

- a single comma separate `var` statement is considered better:

  ```
  var lbutton = element.find("span[class='lb-lk-comm']"),
      dlbutton = element.find("span[class='lb-dlk-comm']");
  ```
- You keep repeating `"lb-voted-comm"`, you should use a constant for it.
- I only understood after reading `likeACtion`/`dislikeAction` that `lbutton/dbutton` stand for `likeButton`, `dislikeButton` ( I thought it was left button, double click button or something ), you should spell out those variables names.

Comment: its lbutton for like button and dlbutton for dislike, its nothing just a span as I have mentioned.

Comment: @Aman I understand, if you actually called the variables `likeButton` and `dislikeButton`, then the code would be of higher quality/readability